# Normalization of Market Data in Time Series Correlation

Tags: time-series, correlation, market-data, pricing, forecasting

Suppose we have 2 time series of market data, one for each security and we want to correlate between these 2 securities. My question is

1. How do we handle gaps of missing data in the time series? Imagine the time series is one day tick data of a stock price and we have a 10 mins gap of missing data sometime during the day.
2. How do we correlate the tick-by-tick market data of these 2 securities that do not happen at the same time for each tick? If we correlate them in the same time intervals, what price do we use?

Comment: You could correlate only where data for both securities is available. Two securities rarely trade at the same nanosecond, so you'll have to create some discrete time interval (eg, 1 minute) for correlation purposes. You can use the median price for the minute to correlate.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for the same issue, I found an article by [de Jong(1997)](http://www.math.ku.dk/~kdh/thesis/docs/highfrequencyanalysisofleadlagrelationshipsbetweenfinancialmarkets.pdf). In section 2 you can find a method for estimation of covariances and correlations between irregularly spaced data. Also look at the article by [Jonas Andersson](https://ideas.repec.org/p/hhs/nhhfms/2007_019.html) where some interpolation methods and method form de Jong are presented and compared together. Hope it helps.

Comment: The first link is dead but try [this one](https://pure.uvt.nl/ws/files/522011/34.pdf) instead.

Answer (score 0):

One assumption is that both (or more) instruments are liquid enough to offer a market (both sides).

You can

1. use the bid/ask/mid (your choice) or
2. "conflate" (implemented by the big boys on their data feeds). i.e. 1 second conflation: if no trade, send out last trade price (or assume so in your application).

Comment: This is not very clear. You should give an example or elaborate more to make this answer really valuable.